# Allow add new post access to custom post but not wp post for some role

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, capabilities, user-roles

I am new to the WordPress.
I have the woo-commerce plugin activated and administrative users can manage admin panel along with woo-commerce orders, coupons etc.
I created new plugin which adds new role in the system called Manager and restricted access to the most of the functionality(using capabilities) like post, pages, plugins and other such things.
Now i want to give access to this manager users to add new, edit, and delete orders from the woo-commerce, but not post.
How do i do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Without knowing your code this is impossible to answer.